# Listen to Socket.io server after require

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, socket.io

When I'm activating the `io` server right after require it works fine, but when I want to do after require my code gives an error when it reaches the first interaction with `io` (defining middleware in my case).

This is working fine:

```
const io = require('socket.io').listen(3002);

const { authValidation } = require('./middlewares');

//Middlewares
io.use(authValidation);
. . .
```

This one gives an error:

```
const io = require('socket.io');

const { authValidation } = require('./middlewares');

io.listen(3002, () => {
  console.log(`Listening to port 3002`);
});

//Middlewares
io.use(authValidation);
. . .
```

The error says that `io.use()` is not a function. I think there is a problem related to the code execution flow and asynchronous stuff, but I can't say what exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try this? I haven't worked with `socket.io` in a while, but I remember it was something like this.

What this does differently is setting `io` to the return value of the `listen` method.

```js
const socket = require('socket.io');

const { authValidation } = require('./middlewares');

const io = socket.listen(3002, () => {
  console.log(`Listening to port 3002`);
});

//Middlewares
io.use(authValidation);
```